# Limiting memory use while creating a huge polars dataframe from pickle files

Tags: python, python-polars

Consider the following code, which tries to create a huge dataframe from a set of pickle files:

```
import pandas as pd
import polars as pl
import glob

pickle_files = glob.glob("/home/x/pickles/*.pkl.gz")

df_polars = pl.DataFrame()

for file in pickle_files:
    df_pandas = pd.read_pickle(file)
    df_temp = pl.from_pandas(df_pandas)
    df_polars = df_polars.vstack(df_temp)

print(df_polars)
```

What I am wanting is to limit the use of memory while running this script, say, up 15GB. Could somebody please guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to first save each of the pickled files in a format Polars knows:

```py
parquet_files = []
for file in pickle_files:
    df_pandas = pd.read_pickle(file)
    df_filename = 'suitable/path/to/file.parquet'
    df_pandas.to_parquet(df_filename)
    parquet_files.append(df_filename)
```

(Of course with a different `df_filename`.) Then we can make a concatenated frame:

```py
df = pl.concat([pl.scan_parquet(file) for file in parquet_files])
```

Now `df` is a single `LazyFrame` you can query.